# MySql exception : Connection need to valid and open. C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert and retrieve data from MySql database using RESTful api. When I performing an insert query, I am getting exception message : Connection need to valid and open.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data;


using WorkAppApi.Models;

namespace WorkAppApi
{
public class DBConn
{
    private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;

    public DBConn()
    {
        string myconnstr;
        myconnstr = "server=192.168.0.103;uid=root;pwd=ganga10lfc;database=readingmeterdb";
        try
        {
            conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = myconnstr;
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {

        }


    }

    public long addMachine(machines machinetosave)
    {


        String sqlstr = "INSERT INTO machines (machineDesc) VALUES ('" + machinetosave.MachineDesc + "')";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlstr,conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
        return id;
    }


}
}
```

> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>     "ExceptionMessage": "Connection must be valid and open.",
>     "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>     "StackTrace": "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n   at WorkAppApi.DBConn.addMachine(machines machinetosave) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\WorkAppApi\WorkAppApi\DBConn.cs:line 41\r\n   at WorkAppApi.Controllers.MachinesController.Post(machines value) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\WorkAppApi\WorkAppApi\Controllers\MachinesController.cs:line 31\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__6(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Comment: Most likely you have an unseen exception while opening the connection in `DBConn()`. Log the exception there since that will provide you most likely with a reason for the later failure

Answer (score 0):

You should open it only where you need it:

```
public long addMachine(machines machinetosave)
{
string myconnstr = "server=192.168.0.103;uid=root;pwd=ganga10lfc;database=readingmeterdb";
    try
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection() conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = myconnstr;
        conn.Open();

    String sqlstr = "INSERT INTO machines (machineDesc) VALUES ('" + machinetosave.MachineDesc + "')";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlstr,conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
        return id;

    }
    catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
    {

    }


}
```

On the side note, you really should be coding with `using(){}` blocks to ensure cleanup / closing of open resources.